# Preposition to use with agreeing

Tags: prepositions

So me and my friend are having this conversation about some product. He says it's great. I haven't tried it yet but I superficially disagree with him. Now that I have tried it, the conversation comes up again and he restates his opinion about the product and I respond with something like this.

"I agree with you about what you are saying about that product, now that I have tried it out myself".

Is agreeing with you **ABOUT** the correct usage of the word? Is the whole sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I agree with you about the rabid dog. It should be put down.
I agree with what you have said about the rabid dog. It should be put down.
```

But I *wouldn't* use "about" twice:

I agree with <del>you about</del> what you have said about the rabid dog. It should be put down.

"about what you have said about" is like the Beatles lyric:

*in this world in which we live in....*

Answer (score 0):

Yes:
agree with [sb] (on/about [sth]): have same opinion

Source: Collins Dictionary